# Loss function depending on the derivative of a neural network with respect to the input in tensorflow

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, loss-functions, tensorflow, gradient

I have a neural network $x \mapsto f(x, \theta)$, and I can access predictions in my code with `out = model(X)`. Imagine that I have a loss function $l(x,y) = (y-\frac{\partial f(x, \theta)}{\partial x}\cdot C)^2$ where $C$ is a constant vector. I think that I can approximate the derivative and write the code like this

```
eps = 0.001
pred = ... # compute the gradient with a formula like (f(x(1+eps))-f(x(1-eps)))/2x*eps
           # and make the dot product with C
loss = tf.math.squared_difference(y, pred) # loss for one data point
```

Is it possible to compute the gradient directly with respect to the input such that the output is still a function of $\theta$ and can be optimized by tensorflow? If so, what should I write in the line `pred = ...`?

Thanks

Comment: Have you considered using PyTorch? Because this can be easily done using the ```torch.autograd``` package in PyTorch.

Comment: Thanks, I will look at it

Answer (score 1):

The best way to picture how this works is that automatic differentiation can be implemented by augmenting your existing computational graph with a few extra nodes / edges (which connect to your "forward comptuation") and compute the gradients. There's nothing which distinguishes these new nodes from your original forward computation (the graph itself is not *aware* of notions of "forward" versus "backward" pass), so it's completely possible to apply AD again, to get higher order derivatives.

Generally speaking, the backward "augmentation" of the graph is usually abstracted away from the end-user, but most machine learning frameworks such as tensorflow and pytorch do expose the relevant utilities, for example [tf.gradients](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/gradients) and [torch.autograd.grad](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/autograd.html).

Comment: Thank you for your explanation